# how to change icon colors dynamically in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to change icons colors dynamically below here:

```
var byillingvalues=[];
for(var i in this.state.Alldata){                       
  byillingvalues.push({bycdata:this.state.Alldata[i].label})
}

var values=byillingvalues.map(function(d,idx){
        let colors=["#F0F8FF","#FFE4C4","#8A2BE2"];
        for(var i=0;i<=colors.length;i++){
              if(i==idx){
               return (<span key={idx}>{<i className="fa fa-square" aria-
                hidden="true" color:colors[i]></i>}&nbsp;{d.bycdata} &nbsp;&nbsp;</span>);
             }

        }   

});
```

How to change icon colors dynamically in react?

Answer (score 0):

The `color` property need to be a style to `i` tag. You need to write

```
<i className="fa fa-square" 
   aria-hidden="true" 
   style={{color:colors[i]}}>
</i>
```

Comment: @VenkaiahVempalla consider accepting the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can pass properties to objects in react using the following

```
class IconList extends Component {
  render() {
    let colors=["#F0F8FF","#FFE4C4","#8A2BE2"];
    return (
      {
        for(var i=0;i<=colors.length;i++) {
          <i 
            className="fa fa-square" 
            aria-hidden="true" 
            style={{color: colors[i]}}
          />            
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var byillingvalues=[];
    for(var i in this.state.Alldata){                               
         byillingvalues.push({bycdata:this.state.Alldata[i].label})
    }
    var values=byillingvalues.map(function(d,idx){
    let colors=
        ["#6cbe45","#347cb5","#6cc1e6","#9d6bad","#4ebe9f","#4ebe9f","#bed730"];                            
    for(var i=0;i<colors.length;i++){
            if(i==idx){     
             return (<span key={idx}>{<i className="fa fa-square" aria-
              hidden="true"  style={{color:colors[i]}}></i>}&nbsp;{d.bycdata} 
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;</span>);
            }
    }

});
```